# Jquery Asp.net mvc Sent Post Order And ID

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to make a post with some page elements but I'm not getting. I want to receive in the post order and item id.

## Jquery

```
var fixHelperModified = function (e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function (index) {
        $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
},
updateIndex = function (e, ui) {
$('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
    $(this).html(i + 1);
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Catv/Index',
    data: { 'order': order },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
});
};

$("#editabledatatablecadatv tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified,
    stop: updateIndex
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: can you show your controller that is meant to receive the post?

Answer (score 0):

```
        public JsonResult Index(cad_atividade u, string order)
    {
        //for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        //{
            //string id = Request["item_ID"];

        string Ordem = order;
            Console.WriteLine(Ordem);
        //    var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("UPDATE cad_atividade SET ORDEM_ATIVIDADE = '" + order + "' WHERE ID= '" + id + "'").ToList();
        //}
        return Json(u, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```